# C++ class that replaces itself?

Tags: c++, arrays, image, replace, rotation

I have been writing a simple C++ class for drawing PPM images. I got to functions where I flip or rotate the image, or copy pixels from one place to another. It occured to me that one way I could do this would be to "replace" the instance from within itself, because rotation is giving me more trouble than I thought it would. My image class stores a pointer to an array of pixels on the heap, and has member variables for width and height. I can rotate the image by creating a new image instance where width and height are swapped, and the new instance's pixel array is filled in using data from the previous image's array ( applying the right rotation math of course ) However, instead of returning the new instance, I'd like the previous instance to reassign its "this" pointer to the new instance. That way, I could use the function like so: image.rotate(90) instead of image = image.rotate(90); I know that's a minor inconvenience, but it's inconsistent with how all the other functions are called.

Here is pseudocode for how I envision the rotation function working:

```
void image::rotate(int angle){ // 0, 90, 180, or 270 degrees only
    // if image is rotated 90 or 270 degrees, swap width and height
    if(angle == 90 || angle == 270){
        image * new_image = new image(height, width);
    }else{
        image * new_image = new image(width, height);
    }

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            // do rotation code here to copy pixel data to new image
        }
    }

    // assign the new image to this instance
    image * old_image = this;
    this = new_image;             // LVALUE REQUIRED AS LEFT OPERAND OF ASSIGNMENT
    delete old_image;

}
```

However, when I attempt this, I get compile error that says the this = new_image line is bad. I'm trying to find better ways to do the rotation that doesn't need to replace the instance, such as creating a new pixel array and redirecting the pointer, but for some reason swapping the width and height is interfering is the save function when I go to write the data to the file so I still have work to do there. This problem has me thinking about the general problem of an instance creating a new instance and replacing itself.

Comment: I think that kind of code was possible in CFront in 1982... then everyone realized it was a terrible idea.

Comment: Define an assignment operator for image and use `*this = *new_image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign to `this` because it is constant. Because it is a special kind of pointer you cannot also declare it.

The type of the `this` pointer for a member function of a class type `X`, is `X* const`. If the member function is declared with the `const` qualifier, the type of the `this` pointer for that member function for class `X`, is `const X* const`.

You can assign to `*this`, so to the object pointed to by `this` pointer.

It seems like possible solution to your problem might be

```
*this = *new_image;
```

This of course assumes that `operator=` is defined for `image`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I just finished the = operator function so I did what you suggested, and it compiles. Program still crashes when I try to save an image after flipping it, get one of those glibc detected errors that I still don't know how to interpret.

Comment: please show the code which is the problem now and we will try to find a cause, do it however in another question